# How do I get the label string value from a :select box in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I have the following in a partial in a Rails 3.2 app using formtastic gem

```
<%= f.semantic_fields_for :bucket do |bucket| %>
                       <%= bucket.inputs do %>
                               <%= bucket.input :bucket_name, :collection => @buckets,
                               :include_blank => false %>
                               <%= bucket.input :sub_directory, :collection =>
@buckets.first.paths,
                               :include_blank => false %>
                       <% end %>
               <% end %>
```

right now in my controller I can get  :bucket_name and the value is ==
to an integer, In my case I only have one item in my collection but it is giving me a value of 2. My guess is this is the ID value of the object.

it's important that I get the actual :name string value of the object
that is selected in the collection. I am not sure how to do this. so
let's say the item I select has a label of "my label" and it's the 3rd
item in the collection. how would I grab the value "my label".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, select inputs will use the `id` attribute of the model as the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tags, and it ties various methods on the object for the contents of the option tag such as `to_label`, `name`, and `to_s`.

You can change both with the `:member_value` and `:member_label` options respectively (these were called `:value_method` and `:label_method` in older versions.

The details of each option are in the documentation for the select input:

http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/SelectInput

Comment: It seems like accessing the object in the DB by using the value passed from the select menu does the trick. I was never able to pass the actual label value. would love to see an example if you have on.

Answer (score 1):

:member_value and :member_label are deprecated from v3 onwards of Formtastic.

Easiest way is to modify the collection passed into the input. See the example from formtastic github page

```
 f.input :author,  :as => :select,      :collection => Author.pluck(:first_name, :id)
```

Here the first_name is the label and id is the value for the select options